# Easy_install celery error

Tags: python, celery

Using easy_install to install celery for python, I get an error when it tries to install billiard, one of the dependencies:

```
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-3.0.6-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for celery==3.0.6
Searching for billiard>=2.7.3.12
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/billiard/
Reading http://github.com/celery/billiard
Reading http://github.com/ask/billiard
Best match: billiard 2.7.3.12
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/billiard/billiard-2.7.3.12.tar.gz#md5=631deb04e69cf6a7cd1f380432a2e420
Processing billiard-2.7.3.12.tar.gz
Running billiard-2.7.3.12/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-g7tRCS/billiard-2.7.3.12/egg-dist-tmp-qEzoAf
warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'Lib'
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Thanks for any advice you may have.

Comment: OS X? What version? And check pls `$ file /usr/bin/cc` and `$ file /usr/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the `Command Line Tools for Xcode` installed. It seems like you are missing a compiler.